# How to extract rows from dataframe based on column specific values using python

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

Currently, I have a huge dataset and a very small sample is shown below. What I want to do is extract rows based on the **shift** column and find the maximum value from the **score** column for **each shift's last 3 rows** and then extract that entire row to a new data frame.

[image]

For example : there are two shifts(Day and Night) for each day and for each shift I want to find the maximum score for **each shift's last 3 rows**(ex: for 26 jun, day shift> i want to find the maximum score from the **last 3 scores** of the day shift,26th jun. I don't want to take each shift maximum score and extract that row ) and extract that entire row and set it to the new dataframe. I want to do this for each day both shifts.

The expected dataframe output is given below:

[image]

I tried to solve this using **groupby**. But I don't know how to find the maximum value from the **score** column **just considering each shift last 3 score values**. I did it considering the entire shift's maximum score.

Comment: Please provide sample data as text, not picture.

Answer (score 0):

To get the last 3 score, use `groupby` and `tail`. To obtain max value, sort on `score` and `drop_duplicates`:

```
df.groupby(["Date", "Shift"]).tail(3)
  .sort_values("score")
  .drop_duplicates(["Date","Shift"], keep="last"))
```